# Creación de un Menú en la parte inferior de la pantalla

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bottom-nav-view

¿Existe en Android una clase que implemente un menú en la parte inferior de la pantalla por defecto?. Algo como esto..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

He estado buscando y no encuentro ejemplos de como hacerlo y tampoco he encontrado nada en la Documentación de Android. Supongo que tendría que ser algo parecido a `TabLayout`.

Si alguien sabe alguna forma de hacerlo pues estaría agradecido. Algo más profesional de lo que tengo hecho yo..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> Resultado de ejecutar el ejemplo del compañero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si , existe el [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html).

asegúrese de agregar esta a tu gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

en tu **layout**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

crear `bottom_navigation_main.xml` en menu y agregar tus items. 
como asi:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_favorites"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_schedules"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_music"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

en tu Activity:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favorites:
                        //Primera
                    case R.id.action_schedules:
                        //Segunda
                    case R.id.action_music:
                        //tercera
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Para más información revisar la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html).

Comment: Gracias! amigo @T.G.ALShammari, voy a echar un vistazo y unas pruebas y te cuento..

Comment: Pues listo. Se ve que no había mirado bien, pero la verdad es que está sencillo de realizar. :)

Comment: De nada amigo , por mas https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Comment: @T.G.ALShammari gracias por tu aportación que es excelente, recuerda que también puedes votar por la pregunta!, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

**Como implementar un [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView)**

Actualmente la forma correcta para agregar un [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView) a tu aplicación es primeramente agregar la dependencia dentro de tu archivo  `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   ...
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
}
```

Agregar dentro del layout en la parte inferior el `BottomNavigationView` :

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

dentro de `res/menu/` agrega el menú en el archivo bottom_navigation_main.xml :

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/action_home"
          android:title="@string/home"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_home" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_favs"
          android:title="@string/favs"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_favs" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings" />
 </menu>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]